# facebook associated as test user role can not get user_likes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Currently I'm creating apps on facebook on development mode, but I need permission to use user_likes, so before I submit this apps for review, I need to test with some user that already associated as test user role.

I'm using javascript and Facebook sdk 2.2, here's my code.

```
FB.api(
    '/me/likes'
,
function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(response && !response.error) {

        alert("YOU LIKE US!");
    } else {
        alert("YOU DON'T LIKE US YET!");
    }
});
```

I always get an empty result.

anyone can help me about how to use user_likes on facebook sdk 2.2?

Comment: You know like gating is not allowed and will never be approved.

Comment: @WizKid but I'm reading on the Facebook guideline is allowed

Comment: @Wiizkid is right, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_likes `Gate access to your app, or some content within your app based on whether or not someone has liked a page.` and https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse chapter 4.5

Comment: @adeade: Where did you read that? As I said your app will never be approved for user_likes so don't spend time on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user login to your apploication, try to add scope on FB.login() to add more permission.

like this

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    }, {scope: 'user_likes'}
);
```

I've same problem and that's solve the problem.

Comment: thanks it's work. I'm added the scope on Fb.getLoginStatus() too.